# Problema con await en un método asíncrono C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, asynctask, asincronismo

Haciendo await a un método asíncrono me salta el siguiente error:

[image: Problema await]

El caso es que el método que ejecuta está tal y como pide:

```
#region Constructors
    public UsuarioCentroViewModel()
    {
        //Singleton
        instance = this;
        .
        .
        .
        //Load data
        EjecutarCenter();

    }
    #endregion

public async void EjecutarCenter()
    {
        await LoadCentroActual();
    }

public async Task LoadCentroActual()
    {
        var centroActual = await apiService.Get<UsuarioCentro>(
             "http://xxx",
            "/api",
            "/xxx",
            TokenType,
            Token,
            0);

        if (!centroActual.IsSuccess)
        {
            await dialogService.ShowMessage("Error", "Error al obtener el centro actual");
            return;
        }

        UsuarioCentroViewModel.GetInstance().CentroActual = (UsuarioCentro)centroActual.Result;

        Usuario = CentroActual.Usuario;
        IdCentro = CentroActual.IdCentro;
        Usuario_Centro = CentroActual.Usuario_Centro;
    }
```

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo y/o sabe alguna forma mejor de hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu problema no esta en el metodo `LoadCentroActual()` si no en el método que ejecuta `LoadCentroActual()`. El método donde se ejecuta `LoadCentroActual()` tiene que estar marcado como `async` para poder utilizar la keyword `await`:

```
public async void EjecutarCenter()
{
   await LoadCentroActual();
}
```

De lo contrario tendras que ejecutar el metodo invocando la propiedad `Task.Result`:

```
public void EjecutarCenter()
{
   LoadCentroActual().Result;
}
```

Comment: Y como referencia, por eso a los metodos se les suele poner NombreDelMetodoAsync, para poder identificar cuales son awaitables...

Comment: Lo he probado como dices y me sigue sin funcionar, es decir, probando con puntos de interrupción se ejecuta el get a la api pero después sale de la función, como si pasase por alto el **await**.  
Por lo tanto no ejecuta a tiempo las siguientes sentencias (Usuario = CentroActual.Usuario, etc) y me carga las vistas sin esos datos.

Comment: @DaniParedes publica el codigo que tienes para poder ayudarte.

Comment: editado el código en la pregunta

Comment: Tuviste en cuenta que al ser una llamada asincrona, los datos puede que todavia no esten disponibles para cuando lo consumas?

Comment: Al tener el **await** en var centroActual = await apiService.Get<UsuarioCentro> espero a recibir el dato, por lo tanto si que deberían estar disponibles

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que crear un método que ejecute `dialogService.ShowMessage()` en un hilo y a ese método le puedes pasar el await, pienso que quedaría algo así:

```
private Task MensajeAsync(){
      return Task.Run(()=>
     {
         dialogService.ShowMessage("Error", "Error al obtener el centro actual");
     });
}

public async void LoadCentroActual()
    {
        var centroActual = await apiService.Get<UsuarioCentro>(
             "http://xxx",
            "/api",
            "/xxx",
            TokenType,
            Token,
            0);

        if (!centroActual.IsSuccess)
        {
            await MensajeAsync();
            return;
        }

        UsuarioCentroViewModel.GetInstance().CentroActual = (UsuarioCentro)centroActual.Result;

        Usuario = CentroActual.Usuario;
        IdCentro = CentroActual.IdCentro;
        Usuario_Centro = CentroActual.Usuario_Centro;
    }
```